# XRegExp: "Unmatched ')'" Yet everything appears to be balanced

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre, xregexp

I've written the following line of code:

```
XRegExp.exec(data,
    XRegExp('<!-- @\[(?<component>[\w+])[\(*(?<classes>[\w+])*\)]*\] -->', 'g'))
```

As you can see it is using the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com) library so I can use named groups other PCRE features.

I'm getting the error:

`syntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /<!-- @[(?<component>[w+])[(*(?<classes>[w+])*)]*] -->/: Unmatched ')'`

However, I don't understand where the unmatched `)` is. As far as I can tell, all brackets that need to be escaped should be and all the ones that shouldn't are not.

Here is the string I am trying to match:

`<!-- @[NoteBlock(warning)] -->`

these should also match:

`<!-- @[NoteBlock(warning, high-level)] -->`

`<!-- @[NoteBlock] -->`

This should not match:

`<!-- @[(warning, high-level)] -->`

UDPATE: Using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ncfNDD/1/) I've managed to get the regex to pass: I've updated the regex to `'<!-- @\[(?<component>[\w+]+)\(*(?<classes>[\w+]+)*\)*\] -->'` however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dv5vqu/1 unmatched `)` is red

Comment: Your regex looks very complicated to me.  I suggest taking it apart in a regex editor until you can get something to work, then build it up.  I see several problems, but I don't have a solution because I don't know XRegExp.

Comment: Make sure you escape your backslashes if you want them to remain a part of the regular expression

Comment: In `(?<component>[\w+])[`, the last `[` is not escaped. It creates a character class. Besides, in a string literal, to define  a backslash you need to double backslashes. Use `"<!-- @\\[(?<component>[\\w+])\\[\\(*(?<classes>[\\w+])*\\)]*] -->"`

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor, that solved it. It's only finding the first match now but that's another problem :)

Comment: Your updated regex doesn't match `<!-- @[NoteBlock(warning, high-level)] -->` (and `<!-- @[/ArticleSection] -->` but maybe it's expected)

Comment: Good spot. It shouldn't match the latter but it does need to match the former, I forgot about that whilst trying to get the rest working, thanks, I'll fix it :)

Comment: All working now, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my answer to meet the new information provided.

Given the example of what you're trying to capture the original regex won't match.

The following will match any characters between [( to component and anything between () to classes.

\w matches a word, digit, or underscore.
This would leave it missing your [-,] characters

Hopefully this helps.

```
<!-- @\[(?<component>[\w]*)\((?<classes>.*?)\)*\] -->
```

@[Component(Classes - warning, highlevel)]

Comment: Small correction: '\w matches a word, digit' - not White Space.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak, I've modified mine to include underscore instead of whitespace.